# Centering vertical text in a div

Tags: css, centering

I have a two column layout with two columns of equal height. I made them the same height using flexbox.

The left column is supposed to contain vertical text which should then be centered along the full height of the column

The HTML looks like this

```
<div class="month">
  <div class="name"><div>Jan</div></div>
    <div class="days">
       <div class="day">123</div>
       <div class="day">123</div>
       <div class="day">123</div>
       <div class="day">123</div>      
     </div>
  </div>
```

And this is the CSS

```
div.month {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.name {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
div.name  div {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: left top 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

div.days {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 20px;

div.day {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Here is an example
http://jsfiddle.net/o6xv824u/

I can't figure out how to center the text in div.month

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to align it vertically center, you can make use of position absolute, "margin-top" and "top" css properties.

I have made some changes in your css code as well. Have a look at [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o6xv824u/3/).

CSS :

```
div.name  div {
      transform: rotate(90deg);
      transform-origin: center center;   // rotate the text from center origin  
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      margin-top: -50%; // to make it align vertically center
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use absolute position then translate.

http://jsfiddle.net/o6xv824u/1/

`position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%;`

`transform: translate (-50%,-50%);`